# Execute Python script from network share to windows system through pssh

Tags: python, ssh, cmd, paramiko, pssh

there is python script in mounted network location (K:/temp/abc.py) in host (Host-01)
I am trying to ssh Host-01 from My PC

but this is not working. Although simple commands like 'whoami' are working.
I tried giving full path as well (//my-net-drive/data/temp/abc.py)

Please suggest how i can run abc.py from net drive through ssh.
It is working fine when I remote log in to Host-01 and run script via cmd prompt

```
from __future__ import print_function

from pssh.clients import ParallelSSHClient

hosts = ['Host-01']
client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts)

output = client.run_command('python K:/temp/abc.py')
for host, host_output in output.items():
    for line in host_output.stdout:
        print(line)
```

Command is executed but no output is shown. When I read output buffer, it is empty. And yes I have tried giving full path to python.exe but still seeing same results

When I copy python file from network drive to desktop and run python file from desktop through ssh it works fine.

Comment: Instead of "not working" you should really include details of what actually happens.

Comment: Please copy and paste the text of any message that appear. Have you tried specifying a fully qualified path to `python.exe`?

Comment: Command is executed but no output is shown. When I read output buffer, it is empty. And yes I have tried giving full path to python.exe but still seeing same results

Comment: What is inside abc.py? because I have tried with simple print statements and its working

Comment: For me even simple print statements are not working. It is not able to run python from shared Drive although if i copy to desktop and ssh same cmd it works fine